# Java: Draw a circular spiral using drawArc

Tags: java, swing, graphics, draw

I'm working on a java programming exercise where we have to draw a circular spiral using the drawArc method so that the result looks similar to this: 
[image]

I've been working on this for a while and this is what I have so far:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class CircSpiral extends JPanel {
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      int x = 100;
      int y = 120;
      int width = 40;
      int height = 60;
      int startAngle = 20;
      int arcAngle = 80;
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         g.drawArc(x, y, width, height, startAngle, arcAngle);
         g.drawArc(x + 10, y + 10, width, height, startAngle + 10, arcAngle);
         x = x + 5;
         y = y + 5;
         startAngle = startAngle - 10;
         arcAngle = arcAngle + 10;
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      CircSpiral panel = new CircSpiral();
      JFrame application = new JFrame();
      application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      application.add(panel);
      application.setSize(300, 300);
      application.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

My code gives me this result:
[image]

I know the problem lies in my arguments for the drawArc method because the numbers aren't right, but I don't know how to go about making the numbers go in a circular manner. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Question edited: Swing tag added. Code formatted to improve indentation and to remove excessive empty lines. Original poster, in the future, please take care and the effort to post code that is well formatted. Code that is easy to read is code that is easier to understand. Thanks for your cooperation in this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your idea is almost right. I did some modifications. You need to inverse the angle to draw the other side of the spiral and use fixed point to `startAngle`.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class CircSpiral extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        int x = getSize().width / 2 - 10;
        int y = getSize().height/ 2 - 10;
        int width = 20;
        int height = 20;
        int startAngle = 0;
        int arcAngle = 180;
        int depth = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                //   g.drawArc(x + 10, y + 10, width, height, startAngle + 10, -arcAngle);
                //  x = x - 5;
                y = y - depth;
                width = width + 2 * depth;
                height = height + 2 * depth;
                g.drawArc(x, y, width, height, startAngle, -arcAngle);
            } else {
                //  g.drawArc(x + 10, y + 10, width, height, startAngle + 10, arcAngle);
                x = x - 2 * depth;
                y = y - depth;
                width = width + 2 * depth;
                height = height + 2 * depth;
                g.drawArc(x, y, width, height, startAngle, arcAngle);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CircSpiral panel = new CircSpiral();
        JFrame application = new JFrame();
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        application.add(panel);
        application.setSize(300, 300);
        application.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If this were my project, yes I'd draw my arcs in a loop, but within the loop, I'd try to make the arc's bounding box bigger but still centered over the same location. To do this I'd decrement x and y by some **small** constant, say DELTA (which I'd set to == 1), and I'd increment width and height by `2 * DELTA`. I'd also leave my arcAngle unchanged but rather would change my startAngle in the loop like so: `startAngle = startAngle - arcAngle;`.

For example, this:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CircSpiral extends JPanel {
   private static final int DELTA = 1;
   private static final int ARC_ANGLE = 20;
   private static final int PREF_W = 300;
   private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
   private static final int LOOP_MAX = 400;

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      int x = PREF_W / 2;
      int y = PREF_H / 2;
      int width = 1;
      int height = 1;
      int startAngle = 0;
      int arcAngle = ARC_ANGLE;
      for (int i = 0; i < LOOP_MAX; i++) {
         g.drawArc(x, y, width, height, startAngle, arcAngle);
         x = x - DELTA;
         y = y - DELTA;
         width += 2 * DELTA;
         height += 2 * DELTA;
         startAngle = startAngle - arcAngle;
      }
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return super.getPreferredSize();
      }
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      CircSpiral panel = new CircSpiral();
      JFrame application = new JFrame();
      application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      application.add(panel);
      application.pack();
      application.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      application.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Would result in this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The following code will output this image:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class CircSpiral extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        int centerX = getWidth() / 2;
        int centerY = getHeight() / 2;

        int numIterations = 5;

        int arcWidth = 10;
        int arcGrowDelta = 30;

        for (int i = 0; i < numIterations; i++) {
            g.drawArc(centerX - arcWidth, centerY - arcWidth, 2 * arcWidth, 2 * arcWidth, 0, 180);
            arcWidth += arcGrowDelta;
            g.drawArc(centerX - arcWidth, centerY - arcWidth, 2 * arcWidth - arcGrowDelta, 2 * arcWidth, 180, 180);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CircSpiral panel = new CircSpiral();
        JFrame application = new JFrame();
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        application.add(panel);
        application.setSize(300, 300);
        application.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The idea is very simple, just draw the upper half of a circle, like this:

[image]

Then increment the arc size by a constant factor and draw the bottom half of the circle but making the end point of this circle and the upper circle match, for it, just substrate the `arcGrowDelta` from the bottom circle width:

[image]

And repeat.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
package mainpack;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SpiralPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

        int width = 10;
        int height = 10;
        int startAngle = 0;
        int arcAngle = 180;
        int x = (getWidth() - width) / 2;
        int y = (getHeight() - height) / 2;

        int i = 0;
        int t = 0;

        while (i < 36) {

            g2d.drawArc(x + t, y, width, height, startAngle, arcAngle);

            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                t -= 10;
            }
            y -= 5;
            width += 10;
            height += 10;
            startAngle += 180;

            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner to java and finally managed how to create the spiral.

Here is my code:

```
int lineLength = 20; //starting line length
int x = getWidth() / 2; //start drawing from center of JPanel
int y = getHeight() / 2; //start drawing from center of JPanel
for( int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++ )
{
    g.drawArc( x, y, lineLength, lineLength, 0, 180 ); //draws top semicircle of equal width and height
    lineLength += 20; //increases arc diameter
    x -= 20; //moves x coordinate left

    g.drawArc( x, y - 10, lineLength, lineLength, 0, -180 ); //draws bottom semicircle; 'y - 10' joins the 2 semicircles
    lineLength += 20; //increases arc diameter
    y -= 20; //moves y coordinate up
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to let some good old trigonometry do the work, you could use this:

```
import java.awt. *;
import javax.swing. *;
import java.math.*;

public class Spiral extends JFrame {

public Spiral()
{
    // Set Window
    setTitle("Spirale");
    setSize(1500, 1500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);
    for(double i = 1; i < 50000; i++)
    {
        int locY = 600 - (int) (Math.cos((Math.PI*i)/1800)*i/50);
        int locX = 600 - (int) (Math.sin((Math.PI*i)/1800)*i/50);
        g.drawLine(locX, locY, locX, locY);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Spiral();
}

}
```